# How to select specific parts from EXPLAIN query results?

Tags: mysql

This  is my first question here. Please let me know if I haven't stated it correctly.

What I'm trying to do is to collect information about a number of MySQL queries stores as views by using EXPLAIN. More specifically I'd like to get a list of tables from which the query selects data. 
I have tried the query below without success:

```
SELECT  v.TABLE_NAME, EXPLAIN v.VIEW_DEFINITION FROM information_schema.views as v
```

So the real question is what is the correct way of doing that?

Comment: So you're trying to do a `EXPLAIN <the query>` but instead you selected all views from the `information_schema` DB? An `EXPLAIN` should return you the query plan MySQL uses, so it should show you the tables used by that query.

Comment: Yes, the whole idea is to run EXPLAIN  on all views and to get a list of referenced tables for each query.

Comment: I doubt you can do that in one query, without the help of a `PROCEDURE` (bc `EXPLAIN` is a keyword for the whole query, not for query's data)

Answer (score 0):

Explain does not return a traditional resultset, therefore you cannot join on it in a query. You need to fetch the results in an application and obtain the additional information you are looking for by running an additional query on information_schema.

The explain itself also returns the underlying table name, so if you are only looking for the name of the table, then explain itself will provide you with that:

```
explain select * from yourview
```

Comment: Yes, I realize I can do that with a simple code but I'm trying to keep it in just one mysql query.

Comment: Well, I do not think you can do that.